# CS50 Mario I'm stuck doing that pyramid

Tags: c, loops, cs50

Well, I've like a week reading all kind of material regarding to C programming to make this pyramid works and finally I decided to ask for help, I've improve a lot, my code now takes the input (0 to 23) correctly and print a new line, but now that I'm trying to add the # into the code, the code make an infinite loop :(.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

/* PSET1 Mario */

int main (void)

{
  int height;

do
{
    printf("Give me an int between 0 or 23 \n");
    height = GetInt();
}while((height < 0)||(height > 23));

//The Pyramid output
int row, space;

space = height - 1;


    for (row = 0 ; row <= height; row++)
    {

            for (space = 0; space < row; space--)
    {
        printf("#");
    }



return 0;
```

}

The main point it is do a pyramid with ''#'' and I edited the post this was my previous code with the #, it was doing a infinite loop.

Comment: Have a closer look at the inner for-loop. You are initializing `space` with 1, but you are decrementing.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. I suspect this is C, so don't add C++ tag.

Comment: "deleted the line that was doing the hashes because it was giving me the infinite loop". Please show that line. If it is just a printf then not sure how that could cause an infinete loop. In any case, you need to show the code that causes problems so that we can help you understand why it causes probelms and how to fix it.

Comment: @kaylym, I'm gonna edit the post and you will see my previous code with the # , and yes, it is ''C'' :( but i didn't know what else should I put as a tag.

DanielR , thank you I will try to take a close look in the for-loops, I still have problem understanding the prefix and postfix part in the increment and decrementing part. :(

Thank you for the response both of you guys!

Comment: @Joan Acosta Show the image of the pyramid.

Comment: As already pointed out: `for (space = 0; space < row; space--)` is of course going to produce an very long loop. `space` is getting smaller and smaller due to the decrement. So `space < row` will be true for a very long time - until `space` underflows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

/* PSET1 Mario */

int main (void)

{
  int height;

do
{
    printf("Give me an int between 0 or 23 \n");
    height = GetInt();
}while((height < 0)||(height > 23));

//The Pyramid output
int row, space;

space = height - 1;


for (row = 0 ; row <= height; row++)
{
    int simbol=0;
       for (space = height-row; space > 0; space--)
   {
       printf(" ");
   }
   for (simbol = 0; simbol < row; simbol++)
   {

       printf("##");
   }


    printf("\n");
}
return 0;
}
```

This give you this pyramid:

```
           ##
          ####
         ######
        ########
       ##########
      ############
     ##############
    ################
   ##################
  ####################
 ######################
########################
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much! And thanks to all the guys that answered me too! :D